# refresh view in navigation controller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I am making an app where in if I tap on a cell of a table, I get navigated to another view. I am posting some data on that page but when I tap on the back button, the records are not updated. I understand it is because, I get the same view from the navigation controller. Can you suggest me a way to reload the data content in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In viewWillAppear:animated:, try this:

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: I did that but my app crashes when I load the tableView he 1st time itself

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CALayer count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6140830'

Comment: Are you using `dismissModalViewController:` for dismissing the **Navigated** View?? you need dismiss that view.

Comment: @iDev - I am assuming you are doing something like this:

You have a UIViewController that contains a UITableView, and that view controller is contained within a UINavigationController.  When you select a cell, you are doing [self.navigationController pushViewController:animated].

Is that correct?  If so, can you post your viewWillAppear code?

Comment: Thanks!! My code worked now.. It was my mistake. Really appreciate your help